# Linear Regression with Non-numeric Variables

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I am trying to run a regression on non-numeric survey data. The question being, does flour type or mixing type lead to a better cake review? Dummy Data is [attached](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h7SmlceB-JsNrInQ6aKumAbKYMth77yJBlUsqKiU0ho/edit?usp=sharing) and factors are explained below

**Flour Type**
White Flour,
Whole Wheat Flour,
Gluten-Free Flour

**Mixing Type**
Kitchen-Aid,
Hand Mixed,
Commercial Mixer

**Cake Review**
Horrible Cake,
Bad Cake,
Okay Cake,
Good Cake,
Great Cake

Can you code the factors into numeric data?

Comment: You might do better to use cake review as an ordered categorical outcome.

Answer (score 4):

This is done by coding the levels of each factor as binary variables (also called dummy or indicator variables). Some software packages do this for you. A linear regression with only categorical dependent variables is called ANOVA.

[This website](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqwhat-is-dummy-coding/) explains pretty clearly what the binary variables look like.

Essentially, you will have a new variable for each level of your factor (e.g. White Flour). The new variable will take the value 1 if that recipe used white flour and 0 if it did not.

Comment: "There will always be one fewer dummy variable than the number of levels." - ISLR, chapter 3, page 86

Comment: I took a stab at coding the variables in sheet 2 but unsure where to go from then 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h7SmlceB-JsNrInQ6aKumAbKYMth77yJBlUsqKiU0ho/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I would code your 'cake review' variable (dependent variable) as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and use a linear regression or a ordinal logistic regression.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For instance, on R, a `lm()` with categorical explanatory variables is the same as an anova performed directly on those categorical variables because the program dummy codes your categorical variables. It's well explained [here](http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/why-anova-and-linear-regression-are-the-same-analysis/)

A.